# Base64 Image data not convert to varbinary(Max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

When I am giving Base 64 data of text with the below code it converts to `VarBinary(Max)`. But when I am trying this same conversion for image data, it returns null instead of `varBinary(Max)`.

SQL Code:

```sql
Select
  CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("r.[PictureBinary]"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') as Image
```

This code works for any text converted to Base64, but if I convert an image to Base64 and use this code to convert the base64 string to varbinary then it returns null.

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempPicture') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempPicture
Declare @Picture xml = '<ArrayOfProductImage><ProductImage><NavPK>10000</NavPK><PictureBinary>3qAAAA==</PictureBinary></ProductImage></ArrayOfProductImage>'

Declare @H_Doc int
EXEC sp_xml_PrepareDocument @H_Doc OUTPUT, @Picture

Select * 
into #tempPicture
FROM
    OPENXML(@H_Doc,'/ArrayOfProductImage/ProductImage',2)
        WITH(
                [NavPK] varchar(100),
                [PictureBinary] nvarchar(Max)
            )
EXEC sp_xml_RemoveDocument @H_Doc
Select * from #tempPicture

Select
  Cast(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("r.[PictureBinary]"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') As Image) as Image,
  'image/jpeg',1,
  r.[NavPK]
From #tempPicture r
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but I see absolutly no C# here...

Comment: Works for me in SQL Server 2012 and 2016.

Comment: May be your image data is corrupt or not of the specified mime-type?

Comment: Base64 encoding turns **binary** data into text - why are you storing that in a  `varbinary` column?? If you're using `varbinary` to begin with - why even bother with a Base64 encoding?? Makes no sense at all..... if you have a binary column - just store the binary image values **as is** - no need to do an extra conversion....